# SP2010 SP2 Beta to Final?

Tags: 2010, service-pack

When the beta version of service pack 2 for SharePoint 2010 was released we could read *"The betas are only designed for use in test environments. An upgrade to the final SP2 versions may not be supported, according to a Microsoft blog post."*

I'm just curious about the words "may not be supported". Now that the SP2 final is released, is there any more information about this - whether an upgrade is supported or not?

Comment: So I downloaded the SP2 final file and installed it - all went fine, I ran SP config wizard - all good, I checked build number in central admin and it had been updated to release version (.7015 instead of .7011), still not sure whether it's supported or not though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinal rule is never, under any circumstances, install the beta of anything onto an environment that can't easily be thrown away or reset (i.e. VM Snapshot of SharePoint *AND* SQL taken before the patch).

At this point, you are really at the mercy of Microsoft so give them a call and plead your case.  They *may* have an upgrade path but my bet is that they will simply tell you that it is not supported and that you have to restore your environment to a pre-beta level and then apply the RTM of SP2.